# Python 2.4 subprocess and grep multiple files on Solaris 10

Tags: python, grep, subprocess, wildcard

Can someone provide proper syntax for running the below grep command through Python 2.4 subprocess method?

```
# grep -n down /tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.*
/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.263:8301:LAES: SS7MGR:  Association Id 2 is down
/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.264:7733:LAES: SS7MGR:  Association Id 1 is down
/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.264:7737:LAES: SS7MGR:  Association Id 2 is down
/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.264:12603:LAES: SS7MGR:  Association Id 1 is down
/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.264:12607:LAES: SS7MGR:  Association Id 2 is down
/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.265:6523:LAES: SS7MGR:  Association Id 1 is down
/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.265:6531:LAES: SS7MGR:  Association Id 1 is down
/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.267:10349:LAES: SS7MGR:  Association Id 2 is down
/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.270:11159:LAES: SS7MGR:  Association Id 2 is down
/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.270:13229:LAES: SS7MGR:  Association Id 2 is down
/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.271:13041:LAES: SS7MGR:  Association Id 2 is down
```

I can get an individual file to work:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-n", "down", "/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.263"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

When I try to grep multiple files it fails:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-n", "down", "/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.*"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such file `/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.*`.  You must pass each file to grep as a separate argument.  The only reason `*` works in the shell is because the shell will expand `*` into multiple arguments before it passes them to grep.

If you want to expand globs, use the `glob` module:

```
import glob

p = subprocess.Popen(
    ["grep", "-n", "down"] + glob.glob("/tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.*"),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You can instead just use `shell=True` as an argument to `Popen`, but that can cause other problems.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of looking around I gave up and posted on stackoverflow only to figure it out a few minutes of testing.

```
p = subprocess.Popen('grep -n down /tmp/support/alarms/SS7Alarms.*', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Putting full command into one string did it.